# Updating local branch from master with Github Mac App?

Tags: git, github

I'm one of a few people working on a repo. The Master branch is more up-to-date than my local branch, and I want to sync my local version so I can continue working from the current state (without screwing anything up). I believe the instructions are [outlined here](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/syncing-your-branch/) but I'd like confirmation that I understand them correctly before implementing them...

Can someone confirm that these steps are correct according to the instructions?

**Set this to master:**
[image: Set this to Master]

**then click sync:**
[image: Click sync]

**then set this to my branch name:**
[image: Set this to my branch name...]

**then click update from master:**
[image: Click "update from master"]

then...
**do some work on my now up-to-date branch of the up-to-date master.
Commit those changes as-needed.**

**then click sync again when I'm ready:**
[image: Click sync again when I'm ready]

Yeah?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may be confused by the github documentation, the steps I outlined above appear to work correctly.